# GPU error on ubuntu

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu

i have this problem, i type
this command

```
sudo CYCLES_OPENCL_SPLIT_KERNEL_TEST=4 blender
```

and it start rendering and says 
*loading render kernels (may take a few minutes the first time)*
then it crashes 
and the terminal reports this

```
Device init success
Compiling OpenCL program split
ASSERTION FAILED: (isa<AllocaInst>(ptr) || ptrCandidate.empty()) && "storing/loading pointers only support private array"
  at file /build/beignet-Bevceu/beignet-1.3.2/backend/src/llvm/llvm_gen_backend.cpp, function void gbe::GenWriter::findPointerEscape(llvm::Value*, std::set<llvm::Value*>&, bool, std::vector<llvm::Value*, std::allocator<llvm::Value*> >&), line 1004
Trace/breakpoint trap
```

please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to be Blender/Cycles issue as much as Beignet (similar open [issue](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/beignet/beignet/issues/2) reported 5 month ago).

It can also happen if your GPU is [unsupported/blacklisted](https://developer.blender.org/rB1f0998baa796f4b25fd745536a8ad71356fb8048). There's [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units) to check - if you have AMD card before GCN 2 then it's unsupported. With supported AMD cards there could be problems on [older drivers](https://developer.blender.org/T52095).